# Graph Editor & F-Curve Modifiers for Material animation

Tags: animation, materials, fcurves

How does one access animation data in Materials in the Graph Editor, so as to better observe Interpolations and use F-Curve Modifiers ?

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share you example? for example I've tried to keyframe a Principled BSDF color or a Mix Shader and it seems to work (I can see the keyframes in the Dope Sheet and in the Graph Editor)

Comment: Ah you are correct @moonboots, I had "Only Show Selected" filtered !   I will delete this posting in a bit, perhaps.